# Why is $\tan135\unicode{176}$ undefined if we use $\tan(A+B)$ formula?

Tags: trigonometry

I know that using identity $\;\tan(90\unicode{176}+\theta)=-\cot\theta\;$,

$\tan135\unicode{176}=\tan(90\unicode{176}+45\unicode{176})=-\cot45\unicode{176}=-1$

But if I use $\,\tan(A+B)\,$ formula

$\tan(A+B)=\dfrac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}\;$,

I get $\,\tan135\unicode{176}=\tan(90\unicode{176}+45\unicode{176})=\dfrac{\tan90\unicode{176}+\tan45\unicode{176}}{1-\tan90\unicode{176}\tan45\unicode{176}}=\dfrac{\infty+1}{1-\infty\cdot1}=\dfrac{\infty}{-\infty}=\mathrm{undefined}$

Why so?

Edit:

Sorry, my bad. $\tan 90°$ is undefined, not equals $\infty$.

Comment: Charlie_23, you should learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

Comment: The addition formula is undefined in the case you cite.  But that doesn't mean the *result* is undefined, it just means you have to use different methods to find that result.

Comment: Surely $\tan 135^\circ$ is defined. Why on Earth would you want to calculate it with a formula outside its range of validity? Do $\tan(60^\circ+75^\circ)$ if you want to, but I would use $\tan\alpha=\sin\alpha/\cos\alpha$ here every day of the week. The moral: never divide by zero, or deal with infinity recklessly. You get what you deserve!

Comment: The formula $\tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}$, holds when both sides are defined. As another example, for $A=35^{\circ}$ and $B=55^{\circ}$  it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because, when you use a formula, every aspect of it needs to be well-defined. You can't use the formula like this, because $\tan 90\unicode{176}$ is not defined. (It is certainly not equal to $\infty$, any more than $\frac 1 0 = \infty$, and we generally avoid doing any math with $\infty$ anyways because it gets very ambiguous and ill-defined very fast; $0\cdot \infty$ for instance.)

It's kind of like when people try to use logarithm properties and observe
$$
0 = \ln(1) = \ln((-1)^2) = 2 \ln(-1)
$$
but $\ln(-1)$ is not defined so this is not a proof $\ln(-1)=0$. (In particular, $\ln(x)$ is only defined for $x>0$, at least with real numbers.)

Or perhaps when they likewise use square root properties and see
$$
1 = \sqrt 1 = \sqrt{(-1)(-1)} = \sqrt{-1} \sqrt{-1} = i^2 = -1
$$
but the property $\sqrt{xy} = \sqrt x \sqrt y$ only holds for $x,y \ge 0$.

Comment: Sorry I have reviewed and found in the textbook that if none of the angles $A, B$ and $(A+B)$ is an odd multiple of $\frac \pi 2$, then the formula for $\tan(A+B)$ holds.

Answer (score 7):

Charlie_23, you cannot use $\tan(A+B)$ formula if $\tan A$ or $\tan B$ is not defined. Moreover, you cannot use that formula even if both $\tan A$ and $\tan B$ are defined but $\tan A\tan B=1$.

But you could proceed in the following way:

$\require{cancel} \begin{align} \tan 135\unicode{176} &= \tan(90\unicode{176}+45\unicode{176})\\ &= \lim_{x\to90\unicode{176}^{\color{red}{\mathbf-}}} \tan(x+45\unicode{176})\\ &= \lim_{x\to90\unicode{176}^{\color{red}{\mathbf-}}} \dfrac{\tan x+\tan45\unicode{176}}{1-\tan x\tan45\unicode{176}}\\ &=\lim_{x\to90\unicode{176}^{\color{red}{\mathbf-}}} \dfrac{\tan x+1}{1-\tan x}\\ &= \lim_{x\to90\unicode{176}^{\color{red}{\mathbf-}}} \dfrac{\color{#8888FF}{\cancel{\color{black}{\tan x}}}\left(1+\frac1{\tan x}\right)}{\color{#8888FF}{\cancel{\color{black}{\tan x}}}\left(\frac1{\tan x}-1\right)}\\ &= \dfrac{1+\frac1{+\infty}}{\frac1{+\infty}-1}\\ &= \dfrac{1+0^+}{0^+-1} =\dfrac1{-1}=-1.\end{align}$

Comment: Interesting tweak on the approach, I like this.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you plugged in angles for $\tan(A+B)$ and got undefined value on the right-hand side. So Let's start from $\tan(A+B)$ and derive right-hand side to see what is going wrong,
$$\tan(A+B) = \dfrac{\sin(A+B)}{\cos(A+B)} = \dfrac{\sin A \cos B + \sin B \cos A}{\cos A \cos B - \sin A \sin B}$$

Now divide numerator and denominator by $\cos A \cos B$. Note that, it is allowed only when $\cos A\cos B \neq 0$

$$\dfrac{\sin A \cos B + \sin B \cos A}{\cos A \cos B - \sin A \sin B} = \dfrac{\tan A + \tan B}{1 - \tan A \tan B}\qquad\text{and}\qquad \cos A \cos B \neq 0$$

Hence,

$$\tan(A+B) = \dfrac{\tan A + \tan B}{1 - \tan A \tan B}\qquad\text{and}\qquad \cos A \cos B \neq 0$$
In other words, you have to pay attention to $\cos A \cos B \neq 0$ which implies both $\tan A $ and $\tan B$ should be defined.

Comment: Thanks. That was an easy explanation :)

Comment: You're welcome!